# size option in gravatar_for helper, ruby on rails, not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

No matter what I put for the size option, the size remains the default 80 x 80. Any ideas why this might be?

```
<%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, options = { size: 100 }), micropost.user %>
```

I thought there might be something in CSS that's overriding the parameter, but couldn't find anything:

```
.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.gravatar {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about another aproach here if it is the https://github.com/mdeering/gravatar_image_tag gem you're using.

```
 <%= link_to micropost.user do %>
    <%= gravatar_image_tag('micropost.user', :gravatar => { :size => 15 })  %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, micropost.user), size: 100 %>
```

For more information on the usage of `link_to` helper method see RoR API here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

A snipet of your HTML code from browser's console would also be helpful here to help you better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!